# Devise - hardcode certain usernames as already taken

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am trying to hardcode certain usernames which users will not be able to select during devise registration.

I didn't find any similar resource on the net and stackoverflow.

My attempt was to do this in users_controller.rb:

```
def create
  if @user.username == "someuser"
    flash.alert = "Username already taken"
    redirect_to new_user_registration_path
  end
end
```

which didn't work and I think its kind of odd to work anyway. Another unorthodox way is to check in applications_controller if the user "someuser" exists to immediately destroy him/her and redirect to signup.

Is there a proper way to do this and hardcode some users during registration?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should do that in model instead of controller

try something like this

```
validates_exclusion_of :username, in: %w( admin superuser ),
  message: "these username are reserved "
```

for more info http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Validations/HelperMethods.html#method-i-validates_exclusion_of

Answer (score 1):

This is in any case something that belongs to the model, not the controller. Most simple way would be to add this as a validation on username like this:

```
validates :username, exclusion: { in: %w(admin superuser) }
```